# How can I install iTunes on command line?

Tags: server, samba, music, shared-folders, iphone

I understand this might not be possible. I save all my music files on a samba share. I have a ubuntu server with no GUI installed. I have two iPhones in my house. On my PC they both have two different libraries. Now I would like to set up my server as my always on iTunes server. So that either of us in my house can connect to our library at any time and sync the music to our phone.

Comment: Not possible. iTunes requires either MacOS or Windows. Some versions can be installed with wine but they do nothing more than play music. It doesn't connect to the store nor enables access to libraries.

Comment: Oh, and it's you again. Hello again. I'll be honest. Either yo adjust your expectations or Ubuntu is not for you.

Comment: Alright. Well thanks. I was only asking a question. Just because I don't know a lot about Ubuntu or know all of its limits doesn't mean I cant use Ubuntu. I can still use it for other things.

Comment: It's not a limit of Ubuntu. Coding a native iTunes for Linux is as trivial as it can be. Why then there isn't one? **Ask Apple**.

Comment: And if I understood correctly your latest comment in your other question, you're running a pure Ubuntu server without desktop environment? If so not even native graphical apps can run, let alone emulated. But why are you using it? Is the machine so old or underpowered? As a home user and a newbie why are you making things more difficult then they should for yourself? You have plenty of time to learn advanced commands. Meanwhile just use something you're familiar with, i.e., a GUI. You can install any DE in Ubuntu server or just use the desktop version which for you is the exact same thing.

Comment: It is a HP MiniServer.

Comment: I see. And you thought "HP server"implies Ubuntu server? No, it doesn't, and again you can add a DE at any time.

Comment: Someones grouchy

Comment: The answer is below. Nothing else to add.

Answer (score 1):

There is no practical way to install a fully functioning iTunes on Ubuntu.  Search for the many questions about this on this site.

Your only recourse is to set up a Windows virtual machine and run iTunes in that.  Assuming you are willing to do that, it works quite well.  I have had to do this to maintain a family member's iPod, although I do not leave it running all the time.